# How to scroll a tilelist using touch (Adobe Air for iOS)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I'm developing an iOS application using Adobe Flash.
It is working fine, except a tile list, that shows a scrollbar and it needs to be dragged to scroll the tile list and show all its content.

Is there a way to make it scroll by just touching and dragging it anywhere?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flex, this will work.

Don't set a height (or width, depending on your needs) and wrap it in a `Scroller` object. I'm not sure if a `TileList` is a valid ViewPort or not, so you may have to do one further level of abstraction and wrap the `TileList` in a generic `Group` object. This will provide a close-to-native scroll functionality to the object within the Scroller.

Example:

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:TileList>
    </s:TileList>
</s:Scroller>
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using Flash.